# Binding list to drop down using append grid library

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Hi I am using jquery appendGrid plugin to show drop down in one of the column. In following code the column name "Origin" has drop down option which works fine.

```
$(function () {
    // Initialize appendGrid
    $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({
        caption: 'My CD Collections',
        initRows: 1,
        columns: [
                { name: 'Album', display: 'Album', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '160px'} },
                { name: 'Artist', display: 'Artist', type: 'text', ctrlAttr: { maxlength: 100 }, ctrlCss: { width: '100px'} },
                { name: 'Origin', display: 'Origin', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: { 0: '{Choose}', 1: 'Hong Kong', 2: 'Taiwan', 3: 'Japan', 4: 'Korea', 5: 'US', 6: 'Others'} }
            ]
    });
```

However the I have a different list that I need to populate that is drop down the partial list is

```
"country": [
        {
            "value": "10",
            "label": "United States"
        },
        {
            "value": "10",
            "label": "UK"
        },
        {
            "value": "20",
            "label": "Aland Islands"
        },
        {
            "value": "30",
            "label": "Albania"
        }]



{ name: 'Origin', display: 'Origin', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: { objects: country  } } }
```

when i run this i get output

```
<option value="objects">[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]</option>
```

Please let me know how can I fix the origin column to show actual values rather than object object. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am also having the same problem.
So I put my all values in an array.

### Then I did like this:

var a = [];
var name; 
for (var i = 0; i < data2.adjustmentEntrylist.objTracker_headAdjustmentEntryGridlist.length; i++) 
{
 name = data2.adjustmentEntrylist.objTracker_headAdjustmentEntryGridlist[i].Name; a.push(name); 
}

$(function () { $('#tblAppendGrid').appendGrid({ 
initRows: 1, 
columns: [ { name: 'Tracker Head', display: 'Tracker Head', type: 'select', ctrlOptions: a } ] });

### });

Hope it will help.